# Gitlab Azure Oauth2 - add identifier to git account as admin

Tags: ubuntu, gitlab, single-sign-on

We have a gitlab server set up on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I have configured it to use Azure oAuth2 to limited success - users are able to sign in via Azure/Office365 when first registering.

What I want is to be able to link users with existing accounts in gitlab to Azure as an Administrator, not have the user do it themselves. I do not, however, know where to find the unique identifier that is added when OAuth is synced. Any ideas?